# What does "legal" mean in legal program?

Tags: word-meaning

This sentence "Programming languages are designed so that each legal program has exactly one meaning" comes from a programming book.

The chapter is "Getting started". This paragraph is trying to explain what semantics is. The whole paragraph is

> The semantics of a language associates a meaning with each syntactically correct string of symbols that has no static semantic errors. In natural languages, the semantics of a sentence can be ambiguous. For example, the sentence “I cannot praise this student too highly,” can be either flattering or damning. Programming languages are designed so that each legal program has exactly one meaning.

I want to know the meaning of "legal" here. Does it mean standard?

Comment: You need to give way more context. Perhaps the title of the chapter or section of the book, and the surrounding text. As it stands, 'legal' has many meanings in connection with software licensing, and possibly within the context of programming too.

Comment: The chapter is "Getting started". This paragraph is trying to explain what semantics is. The whole paragraph is "The semantics of a language associates a meaning with each syntactically correct string of symbols that has no static semantic errors. In natural languages, the semantics of a sentence can be ambiguous. For example, the sentence “I cannot praise this student too highly,” can be either flattering or damning. Programming languages are designed so that each legal program has exactly one meaning."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In computing "legal" and (more often) illegal means "(not) permitted by the system.   For example, an "illegal instruction" is an instruction (at the machine code level) that has no opcode or is otherwise forbidden.

In a similar way, a "legal move" in chess, is a move that is permitted by the rules of the game.  Moving a pawn three spaces forward, or moving your king into check is illegal, within the rules of chess.  A legal move might be a bad move, or not.

So a "legal program" is one that follows the strict rules of the computer language.  Every legal C program must have one function called "main".  `print 2+3` is legal in python 2, but not in python 3.

Comment: In principle, I think "legal" code should be any code capable of being compiled. But increasingly, the distinction between "error" and "warning" is being eroded by modern compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: "capable of being compiled" ... not much use for an interpreted language.  And the old notion of "undefined behaviour" means that compilers can compile programs that are not legal.